# 2005 Honda Civic - Oveheating

Tags: engine, cooling-system, overheating, head-gasket, cooling

So my car has been overheating for over 1 year. It overheated during summer or when I went 80mph only.  I recently saved up enough money to get the car fixed.

I brought it to my mechanic and informed him of how long it was overheating for. He replaced the water pump, thermostat and radiator and timing belt and a few gaskets. He said he test the head gaskets several times and said it came back negative as being blown. So he did not replace the head gasket and I don't think he visually inspected it.

The car drove good for one day then it ran awful. I brought it back and sure enough a spark plug was misfiring. We could see water leaking into that cylinder which caused the plug to misfire. He told me the head gasket is the problem. He then told me to use bars leaks liquid copper block seal, so I can just add it to the antifreeze at home. I added the solution at home when the engine was cool. I then ran the car for 20 minutes following all directions.

The next day the car ran perfect no overheating. After I left work I was driving home and I heard a pop and fluid came out on my hood and windshield. I then noticed my car was overheated to the max. I added water to the radiator and it all came out under the car within 2-3 seconds. I brought it back to the shop and the mechanic said he thinks I should just have a used engine installed in my car.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Is it just the head gasket that needs to be replaced or is it something else? If I do put in a used engine couldn't I possibly run into the same situation down the road?

Comment: It sounds as though one of the freeze plugs has given way. I'm surprised the mechanic didn't *tell* you what the issue was instead of just giving you the *need a new engine* song and dance.

Comment: Too many possibilities for this to be usefully answerable. Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

For starters it's never a good idea to add additives to you radiator, they might work short time then cause major problems down the road, as I'm sure you know now. Sound like it's gonna be a lot more work to fix your existing engine, blown head gasket, I'm sure flushing Orr cleaning top end, or worst, That was some bad info from a self proclaimed mechanic. New engine might be the best choice, and make sure the used engine doesn't have blown head, I'd get another mechanics opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the water came out almost instantly it sounds like it could be a radiator hose or heater hose...I'm thinking heater hose since you mentioned it was all over your windshield.